# word usage - clear and understandable

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, synonyms

Consider the scenario where I am explaining a math solution to a student.
Now to check if he understands it I could ask -

1. Is this clear
2. Is this understandable?
   Are the above two sentences correct to use? 
   Any suggestions for alternatives to express the same ?